# SharePoint 2013 convert existing web app/site to Share Point 2010 compatibility mode

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Is there a way to convert existing site so that it runs in SP2010 compatibility mode/has 2010 experience version? I see that I can control compatibility range for web app and further for newly created sites within it. But what about existing sites? Especially can I downgrade? I'm doing this for testing purposes, so it is OK to use something not fully supported by MSFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe you can downgrade the existing site collection to 2010 mode. Once it upgrade to 2013 mode or newly created site collection under 2013 mode, they cant be downgrade.

But if you are talking about the migrated site collection then there may be a way. Like, if you have backup of your site collection/Content Database from 2010 then you can remigrate it to 2013 and leave it in 2010 mode.

Another Workaround is, 3rd party tools allow u to move the data between various version. Check if they allow to downgrade it. i.e sharegate or metalogix.